# jQueryUI Dialog Position and Size

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to create a dialog using jQueryUI and I'm running into 2 issues that I didn't expect and haven't found a solution that seems to work for me. Using this code:

```
$( '<div/>' ).load( $this.attr( 'href' ) ).dialog({
  height: 'auto',
  maxWidth: 600,
  position: 'center',
  resizable: false,
  title: $this.attr( 'title' ).length > 0 ? $this.attr( 'title' ) : false,
  width: 'auto',
  resize: function( e, ui ) {
    $(this).dialog( 'option', 'position', 'center' );
  }
});
```

I end up with a dialog that's positioned such that the upper left corner is at the center of the screen (or thereabouts) and whose width seems wholly dependent on the text it contains. Is there something obvious that I'm missing? I'd really like for the dialog as a whole to be center aligned on both axes and for the width to not exceed 600px.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `width: 'auto'` is the culprit, I think. Also, the `resize` function doesn't apply to whether the browser window resizes, that was just if you `resize` the dialog itself. Since you set `resizable` to `false`, that won't happen.

How about setting a `minWidth` as well?

```
$( '<div/>' ).attr('id', 'my-dialog').load( 'hello.html' ).dialog({
  height: 'auto',
  maxWidth: 600,
  minWidth: 500,
  position: 'center',
  resizable: false,
  title: $this.attr( 'title' ).length > 0 ? $this.attr( 'title' ) : false,
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#my-dialog').dialog( 'option', 'position', 'center' );
});
```

More in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: That was it. I've gotten so used to using `width: 'auto'` that I completely missed its presence. Now I just need to center the window vertically and I'm good. Thanks.